# Android auto plays videos without rooting

Tags: ford

few days back i bought a new ford aspire titanium plus car. Android auto is there. My question is how can i play videos on screen by using android auto. Any help may appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "rooting"? Booting perhaps?

Comment: By *rooting*, are you suggesting you want to do something to the car's Android to enable it to do things it would normally not do?  Like rooting a smartphone?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about a mobile phone app, not about vehicles.

Answer (score 3):

1. You are asking questions about a mobile phone app in *Motor vehicle Maintenance and Repair*, that the app interfaces with your car doesn't count. I'm not asking questions about Spotify here either, while it does play on my car stereo over bluetooth...
2. Android Auto is not designed to play video on your car's screen. it is meant to provide a distraction-free interface with the most basic car-related features enabled: navigation, audio and some text-to-speech services. Showing video is not part of that, if you would have googled it you would have known.